# Behring custom made bike

Tags: frames

Hoping someone can help me as I don't know much about bikes.

I bought a 10 speed bike at a garage sale which the owner said was custom made by a bike maker in St. Louis, MO.  She said the frame was chromoly steel.  The frame has the name "Behring," which I assume was the builder, and there is a label on the bottom tube which says "Columbus Tubing."

Is anyone familiar with a bike of this description?  I have some pictures if that would help.

Comment: You should post the pictures, but Columbus is a brand of steel from which the bike is made.

Comment: I am not really sure what the question is here.  Are you just trying to find out if Behring was a brand?

Comment: No hits in Google.  It could be a small frame builder -- there were quite a few a few decades back, when a 10-speed would have been built.  Most have unfortunately disappeared due to Chinese competition and the current infatuation with exotic materials.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently George Behring used to be [a framebuilder in the St. Louis area](http://stlbiking.com/forum/index.php/topic/5329-custom-frame-builders-in-stl/#entry33632), and was a racer and a member of the [Saint Louis Cycling Club](https://www.facebook.com/StLouisCyclingClub). Unfortunately, like many small builders of the 1980s, there's very little information about him or his bikes on the web.

Comment: @wheatshocker you know - if you posted a picture of your bike, and what you know about it, then you would have tripled the amount of Behring information on the web.   Go on - do it!